# Method for printing Arraylist returns []

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to make a booking system for a hotel using the MVC dp. I have a class with a fixed arraylist of rooms (from 1-25) inside the model and class in which I have the showAvailableRooms method in the controller package . I'm asking my View to print out the available rooms but the only thing it prints out is two square brackets ([]).

P.S. The get OccupiedRoom is another method I have in my bookinglist class (model). It checks if the dates you pass it as arguments are a problem to already existing bookings,if it is then it checks if the room is already in that occupied list and if it isn't it adds it to the list.

```
 public void showAvailableRooms(MyDate arrivaldate, MyDate departuredate) {
        ArrayList<Room> availablerooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < l.getOccupiedRoom(arrivaldate, departuredate).size(); j++) {
                if (h.getRoom(i) != l.getOccupiedRoom(arrivaldate, departuredate).get(j)) {
                    availablerooms.add(h.getRoom(i));
                } else if (l.getOccupiedRoom(arrivaldate, departuredate).size() == 0) {
                    System.out.println(h.getAllRooms());
                }
            }

            System.out.println(availablerooms);
        }
```

Comment: those twoo brackets `[]` very likely mean your list is empty

Comment: Small addition, try checking that with your debugger. Put a breakpoint before the print statement and see the current value at that piont.

Comment: are you doing a right compare here: ***(h.getRoom(i) != l.getOccupiedRoom(arrivaldate, departuredate).get(j)*** ????, bcause that is the only one condition I see you need to meet to add elements to the list

Comment: It appears to missing a `}`

Comment: Since we dont know what is inside the "l" and "h" lists it's difficult to give an exact response. Can you give the code from those other classes aswell?

Comment: would you please add your Class `Room` definition .. because you are comparing two `Room` Object using `Relational operator` which is not possible to compare two User-Defined class without Overriding `compareTo` method.  Thank you

Comment: l is an instance of my Ledger class that holds all of the bookings and h is an instance of my Hotel class that holds all the rooms.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap actually it is possible, if `h` and `l` holds references to same objects , it will work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is poor quality, and person who asked it already remove his SO account.

Answer (score 0):

As i said in comment `[]` means your list is empty.
you add elements to `availablerooms` only in your inner loop, but if `l.getOccupiedRoom` returns you empty list, then code inside inner loop won't be executed, and no empty rooms will be added.

Comment: But what about me else if? It should return all of the rooms if the occupied list of rooms is empty

Comment: @user6299442 that if statement you are reffering to is else block for if defined within inner loop. if you remove else keyword then it will work

Comment: I recently added it, even without it it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

two square brackets ([]). Means that availablerooms doesn't have any entry. Either there are no available rooms, or it isn't getting populated correctly. Please check your logic.